# Object creation on the spot vs variable declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code (to split a string into a vector) that gives me segfault on the second iteration of the for_each loop:

```
std::string command = "Something something something";
std::sregex_token_iterator splitter {command.begin(), command.end(), std::regex{"\\s+"}, -1};
std::sregex_token_iterator splitter_end;
std::for_each(splitter, splitter_end, [&](std::ssub_match sm) {
    cmd.push_back(sm.str());
});
```

Trying to understand what was going on, I detached the declaration of the regular expression as a named variable and it started working:

```
std::string command = "Something something something";
std::regex rx {"\\s+"};
std::sregex_token_iterator splitter {command.begin(), command.end(), rx, -1};
std::sregex_token_iterator splitter_end;
std::for_each(splitter, splitter_end, [&](std::ssub_match sm) {
    cmd.push_back(sm.str());
});
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: You could use `std::stringstream` to split the string easily (If the separator is a space).

Comment: See [std::regex_token_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator). The constructors takes a const reference to the _regex_. That's bad. I think they should add a _deleted_ overload with an rvalue reference.

Comment: not sure how the first version passed compilation. should use new there no?

Comment: What's a version of your compiler ? GCC before 4.9.0 had failed with std::regex's

Comment: Has this been tried with CLang++ (e.g. 3.3 or newer)?  I am curious to know whether CLang compiles `std::regex` correctly for both versions.

Comment: @nosid, How is it bad? If you bind an rvalue to a const reference, the rvalue lives as long as the reference lives.

Comment: Looks like a temporary `std::regex` should not be used in this way, and the fact that this code compiles is a defect in the C++11 library that is being fixed for C++14.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know the answer, but I don't like it. I think this may be a defect in clang.

`std::sregex_token_iterator` is saving pointer to regular expression.

In the first version, the anonymous `std::regex` object is destructed after `splitter` is constructed. This leaves `splitter` pointing at a deallocated space in memory.

In the second version, `rx` will live until the end of the block. This leaves `splitter` pointing at a proper object.

---

`std::regex_token_iterator` constructor

```
template <class _BidirectionalIterator, class _CharT, class _Traits>
regex_token_iterator<_BidirectionalIterator, _CharT, _Traits>::
regex_token_iterator(_BidirectionalIterator __a, _BidirectionalIterator __b,
                     const regex_type& __re, int __submatch,
                     regex_constants::match_flag_type __m)
: __position_(__a, __b, __re, __m),
_N_(0),
__subs_(1, __submatch)
{
    __init(__a, __b);
}
```

Constructs `__position_` of type `std::regex_iterator`:

```
template <class _BidirectionalIterator, class _CharT, class _Traits>
regex_iterator<_BidirectionalIterator, _CharT, _Traits>::
regex_iterator(_BidirectionalIterator __a, _BidirectionalIterator __b,
               const regex_type& __re, regex_constants::match_flag_type __m)
: __begin_(__a),
__end_(__b),
__pregex_(&__re),
__flags_(__m)
{
    _VSTD::regex_search(__begin_, __end_, __match_, *__pregex_, __flags_);
}
```

This is storing the address of `__re` as in a pointer. Once `__re` goes out of scope, `__re` is destructed `__position_` is left with a dangling pointer.

---

**Final Note**

The following works:

```
std::string command = "Something something something";
std::for_each(std::sregex_token_iterator{command.begin(), command.end(), std::regex{"\\s+"}, -1},
              std::sregex_token_iterator{},
              [&](std::ssub_match sm) {
    cmd.push_back(sm.str());
});
```

This is because the anonymous `std::regex` has a lifetime the same as the anonymous `std::sregex_token_iterator` object.